# Einige for singular and Einige for plural

Tags: difference, pronoun, article, grammatical-number

I'm not able to understand when to use the single form of **einige** and when to use it in plural form.
From my understanding **einige** can be used only in plural form.

https://www.verbformen.com/?w=einige

Shows that **einige** can also be used in singular form.

Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: I'm not sure that 'einig(e)' makes sense in singular and until shown a counter-example I'd argue it's an error in the page / learning material. Not to be confused with the adjectiv/adverb "einig" as used e.g. in the German national anthem.

Comment: @planetmaker https://www.dwds.de/wb/einige#wb-1

Comment: @Teo: Welcome in German Language SE. *Thank you* comments are polite, but not typical in SE generally and will likely be removed. If you found some comment or answer useful, click the corresponding *upvote* icon.

Answer (score 4):

Note, that *einige* has two meanings, as stated one the [DWDS page](https://www.dwds.de/wb/einige#wb-1) already given by @Roland (I skip colloquial meaning number 3 here).

- Meaning 1, *einige Kinder*, translating to *several (children)* of course requires plural.
- Meaning 2, *einige Mühe*, translating to *a substantial amount (of effort)* requires singular.

Comment: Ok, I think i grasped the difference, but for the singular form I will need to use the declensions of the neuter gender ? Also, can I say that **einige**,in way, is the plural form of undefined article **ein** **eine** **ein** ?

Comment: @Teo: First question: no, *Mühe* is feminine, for neuter (*einiges Kopfzerbrechen*) endings are different. Second part: Also no, the indefinite article vanishes, when plural is required, see e.g. [here](https://mein-deutschbuch.de/unbestimmter-artikel.html). If I misunderstood something, feel free to create a separate question.

Comment: This is similar to the English equivalent *some*. E.g. *einige Mühe* = *some effort*. *Einige* here describes the amount (uncountable) rather than the number of "efforts" (*einige Mühen* would have a similar meaning, but stresses multiple instances rather than one big task).

Answer (score 2):

The forms are correct. Examples that you'll find frequently are e.g. "mit einiger Mühe" (with some / a lot of effort), "Ich habe einiges zu erzählen".

It is like with "alle - alles" or "beide - beides"

The Duden grammar writes (2022 ed., §1272):

"Wenn sich Pronomen nicht auf eine Nominalphrase beziehen und für etwas Un- belebtes stehen, erhalten sie das Merkmalbündel »Neutrum Singular«. Pluralformen sind dann ausgeschlossen – selbst bei Lexemen, deren Formen sonst gewöhnlich im Plural stehen:
(8) Der Titel klingt nach Lebenshilfe, der Name des Autors wie ein Pseudonym, aber *beides* ist falsch. /  Auf dem Schrottplatz stand *einiges* herum: neun Lastwagen und drei Bagger."

Comment: Incidentally, would you translate (8) as "...both is wrong" ? Same phenomenon?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kindly response